# Aliasing object methods in D

Tags: alias, d

Suppose I've imported `std.algorithm.BinaryHeap`, and want to call its `removeAny` method something else (for instance, `delete_min`). If I were importing the method from `std.algorithm` itself, I could write something like this:

```
import std.algorithm: removeAny;
alias delete_min = removeAny;
```

However, I obviously cannot do that, as `removeAny` is a method of `BinaryHeap`. How can I alias it to something else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the best, if not the only way to do this is to define a short extension method:

```
auto delete_min(T...)(ref BinaryHeap _this, T other_args_here) {
    return _this.removeAny(other_args_here);
}
```

Then you can call that as `yourthing.delete_min(other_args)` and the compiler ought to inline it removing the other little layer.